# Row inside column, non-row children becomes centered in the cross axis, why? Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

This is a problem I encountered when watching a tutorial for Flutter. So let us say we have a column, and then inside the column one of the children is a row which also has children. Then for an unknown reason the children of the column which are not a row becomes centered horizontally. In this case the mainAxisAlignment is set to MainAxisAlignment.center. Now the tutorial presents an elegant solution to make the non-row children be at the same alignment as the children of column that is a row, that is to set the crossAxisAlignment to CrossAxisAlignment.start.

I simply want to know why this phenomenon happens. Is it perhaps because by inserting a row, it programatically sets the crossAxisAlignment of the column to CrossAxisAlignment.center? I don't see how the code can logically act like that though. The code is below.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("Aplikasi Hello World"),
            ),
            body: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Text 1'),
                Text('Text 2'),
                Text('Text 3'),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Text 4'),
                    Text('Text 5'),
                    Text('Text 6')
                  ],
                )
              ],
            )));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Row automatically takes as much horizontal space as available. It stretches the Column widget to its maximum width.
Column has by default cross axis alignment of center. You will have to change cross axis alignment value to crossaxisalignment.start to make those non-row widgets in start.

Comment: Oh wow I never realized that. Thanks for your answer.